Puedo utilizar python 3.9 específicamente en anaconda si ya se ha actualizado?
necesito saber si podría utilizar Python 3.9 desde Anaconda a través de spyder. esta pregunta me surge por que actualice el navegador anaconda y necesito utilizar el interprete de spyder pero con Python 3.9 y bueno, luego de la actualización se ejecuta spyder pero con Python 3.11. Realmente necesito usar específicamente 3.9 puesto que estoy realizando mi tesis y estoy generando la base de datos. dicha base de datos la realizo a través del simulador PowerFactory. Podría ayudarme por favor, tenga feliz dia.

Entonces qué necesitas? Que anaconda use la versión 3.9 o que spyder use la versión 3.9? Si es anaconda, mira esta documentación https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-python.html

Agregando a lo comentado por Mateo, en Spyder puedes seleccionar el intérpete a usar en Herramientas >> Preferencias >> Intérprete de Python (si no me equivoco, estoy escribiendo de memoria). Por defecto usa el mismo intéprete en el que eĺ mismo está instalado, pero puedes usar el que quieras.
